# Computing the Chebyshev center of a V-representation polyhedral cone

Tags: linear-programming, convex-geometry, convex-cone

I'd like to compute the Chebyshev center of a convex polyhedral cone (restricting the center to be inside the unit hypercube).

Given a polyhedral cone in H-representation (linear inequalities $\mathbf{A}x\leq 0$), the Chebyshev center can be easily computed by a linear program.

However, I only have the V-representation of the cone:

$$ \{ x \   |  \ x=\mathbf{C} \mathbf{\lambda}, \ \mathbf{\lambda}_i \geq 0 \ \ \forall i \} $$

The issue is that for my problem, $x\in \mathbb{R}^{84}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ has dimension $84 \times 162$. I think the facet enumeration problem of converting from V- to H- representation is too expensive because the cone is in a high dimensional space. Is there a way to compute the Chebyshev center directly from the V- representation?

Comment: Could you give a reference to what is a "Chebyshev center": it is not a well known concept.

Comment: Why don't you answer my question ? This site is based on dialog...

Comment: The Chebyshev center is the largest ball that can can be inscribed in a set. For the case of a polytope specified linear inequalities, a linear program can compute the Chebyshev center: https://web.archive.org/web/20140912204904/http://www.ifor.math.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/intro_ss11/Exercises/solutionEx11-12.pdf